# Two tables referencing each other in Entity Framework 6 Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I have the entities `Project` and `Sprint` where a Sprint belongs to a Project. A Project also contains a `Backlog` which is a reference to a single Sprint it will add items to by default.

```
public class Project
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long BacklogId { get; set; }
    public Sprint Backlog { get; set; }
}

public class Sprint
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework obviously can't determine the relationship between these two entities just from the above and throw

> Additional information: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Sprint' and 'Project'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

I've been trial-and-erroring a lot and cannot get passed various issues such as 'Multiplicity is not valid in Role' issues.

How do correctly I model this relationship I've described correctly using either Data Annotations or `OnModelCreating()`. I currently have

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Sprint>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.Project)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Backlog);
}
```

*Background: I'm using EF6 and connecting to an Sqlite file using the `System.Data.SQLite.EF6` provider*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `OnModelCreating()` worked and seems correct.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Sprint>()
        .HasKey(s => s.ID)
        .HasRequired(s => s.Project)
        .WithMany(p => p.Sprints)
        .HasForeignKey(s => s.ProjectId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
        .HasKey(p => p.ID)
        .HasOptional(p => p.Backlog);
}
```

It was important to set Backlog as optional using `HasOptional` using `modelBuilder` and making `Project.BacklogId` nullable with `long?`. otherwise there's a circular reference and we won't be able to create either entity. It made sense to keep the Backlog reference on Project (as it belongs to the Project) instead of creating an `IsBacklog` on Sprint.

With the additional reference to `Project`'s collection of `Sprint` *- thanks to [@fejesjoco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27088107/80428) and [@Zakos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27090274/80428) for pointing this out*

```
public class Project
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Sprint> Sprints { get; set; } // new
    public long? BacklogId { get; set; } // changed
    public Sprint Backlog { get; set; }
}

public class Sprint
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

## Important Note

Even though `Project.BacklogId` is nullable, Entity Framework sees this as a circular reference and throws a **[DbUpdateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateexception%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)**:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

As it turns out there's [ticket #142](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/142) on EF's bug/idea list reported in late 2012 with exact same problem. It's current status is proposed and there's a comment by an EF rep saying:

> We agree that this would be a good scenario to enable. Taking into account where we are in the EF6 release along with the size and the impact of this feature our team is not planning to implement it in EF6. Therefore, we are moving it to the Future release to reconsider in the next release.
>
> *- RoMiller wrote Jan 25, 2013 at 9:17 AM*

### Workaround

The way to overcome this is to save to the context twice inside a transaction

```
using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        var project = new Project { Name = "Project 1" };
        context.Projects.Add(project);
        context.SaveChanges();

        var backlog = new Sprint { Name = "Backlog", Project = project };
        project.Backlog = backlog;
        context.Sprints.Add(backlog);
        context.SaveChanges();

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you actually need two distinct relationships. There's a 1:0..N between project and sprint (all the sprints of a project), and 0..1:1 between project and sprint (the backlog sprint of the project), so you need two model builder statements. `Sprint.ProjectId` is the FK of the first association, `Project.BacklogId` is of the second. Of course, this layout allows you to specify a backlog which doesn't belong to the project, so you need to validate that. Alternatively, you could introduce a `Sprint.IsBacklog` flag, in that case you would only need one association.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks I will give this a shot. I considered IsBacklog before but I didn't think my model was that complex to be honest

Answer (score 0):

This works with EF Core.

```
public class Project
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // explicit constraint is required to resolve child-dependent relationship
    [ForeignKey("BacklogId")]
    public virtual Sprint Backlog { get; set; }
}

public class Sprint
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // explicit constraint is required to resolve child-dependent relationship
    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}

var project = new Project { Name = "Some project" };

// intermediate saving is required to avoid circular dependency exception
context.Projects.Add(project);
context.SaveChanges();

var backlog = new Sprint { Name = "Backlog sprint", Project = project };
project.Backlog = backlog;

context.Sprints.Add(backlog);
context.SaveChanges();
```